How do I feed the output arrow (`Input0_ProcessInputRow()`) of a second Script Component with data from a temp table of the first Script Component?
Here is the full setup and code that takes up this answer at DFT drops connection and its temporary table after leaving any DFT item, tested with two Script Components. How do I keep the temp table alive?. Testing this answer made clear that in the second Script Component, you can only work on the temp table that was made in the first Script Component if you are in the PostExecute() method.
From this arises the broader question how a temporary table can be passed to another Script Component and then still be available before the output arrow is fed by the Input0_ProcessInputRow() method.
Here is the marked data output arrow that this question is about:

It comes out of the Second Script Component and shall be written to a regular table in the last item.
20240422 full check for you to copy and paste
I got the hint from the other answerer that the temp tables are meant to be there for the whole session, in any of the methods, and that it therefore must be my own project and server setup or code that makes temp tables readable only in PostExecute(), and that it might be linked to the global "##" temp tables that I took instead of "#".
I checked it again, in all methods, with the #temp tables and ##temp tables, and it did not fix it, see the new remarks below. Thus, I still do not know how to get this done so that a temp table can feed the output arrow with data. The other answer does not work (enough) for me, I can only see the data in and after the PostExecute() method, at a time when you cannot fill the output arrow anymore.
In the end, it also might be a rights issue of the connection manager or something else in my SQL Server setup as there is no minute without at least a dozen temp tables. If anyone wants to test this to prove me wrong, I am happy to know for sure that it is just my own setup. I have now tested this in two bigger test runs, to no avail.
Connection Manager

The connection manager is called tempdb_pkg in the following, but the container was run with these settings.
Control Flow

Data Flow Task
With items 1 to 4

Mind that the fourth item (OLE DB Destination) above cannot be reached with data from a temp table, see chapter "Item 4" below. What you see here cannot be done.
Item 1: OLE DB Source

Get a test data source with two columns of values 'hello' and 'world'

Some select from the database:

select 'hello' as col1, 'world' as col2

Item 2: Script Transformation

Write it to #(#)temporary_table




#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
#endregion

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    private SqlConnection conn = null;
    //private static string connectionString => @"...;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI";
    private DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //private string connectionString;

    public override void AcquireConnections(object Transaction)
    {
        //base.AcquireConnections(null);
        //string connectionString = Connections.Connection.ConnectionString;
        //conn = new SqlConnection() { ConnectionString = connectionString };
        conn = (SqlConnection)this.Connections.Connection.AcquireConnection(null); // Acquire the connection
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        conn = (SqlConnection)this.Connections.Connection.AcquireConnection(null);
        conn.Open();
    }

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();

        conn = (SqlConnection)this.Connections.Connection.AcquireConnection(null); // Acquire the connection
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        conn.Open();

        // create temp table, make sure it matches your input
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temporary_table;
    CREATE TABLE #temporary_table(
        [col1][varchar](30) NULL
        ,[col2][varchar](30) NULL
    )", conn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        // Iterate over input columns to get original column names for the dt
        foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 inputColumn in this.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection)
        {
            // Get the original column name
            string originalColumnName = inputColumn.Name;

            // Add column to DataTable with the original column name
            dt.Columns.Add(originalColumnName, typeof(object));
        }
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        // Create DataRow to store values
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        // Iterate over input columns to get original and then modified column names for the chosen Row
        foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 inputColumn in this.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection)
        {
            // Get the original column name
            string originalColumnName = inputColumn.Name;

            // Get modified column name for checking null values in Row object
            string modifiedColumnName = originalColumnName.Replace("_", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");

            // Check if the column is null
            PropertyInfo isNullProperty = typeof(Input0Buffer).GetProperty(modifiedColumnName + "_IsNull");

            if (isNullProperty != null)
            {
                bool isNull = (bool)isNullProperty.GetValue(Row);

                if (isNull)
                {
                    // Handle null value as needed
                    // For example, you can set it to DBNull.Value
                    dr[originalColumnName] = DBNull.Value;
                    continue; // Skip to the next column
                }
            }

            // Get property with matching name from Row object
            PropertyInfo property = typeof(Input0Buffer).GetProperty(modifiedColumnName);

            // Check if the property is null
            object value = property.GetValue(Row);

            // Add value to DataRow
            dr[originalColumnName] = value;
        }
        // Add populated DataRow to DataTable
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        // here we would bulk copy data into the temp table
        // you may need to batch this operation or handle it differently based on your situation
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
        {
            // Now write that DataTable to the database 
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "#temporary_table";
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            bulkCopy.Close();
        }

        Connections.Connection.ReleaseConnection(conn); // Release the connection
                                                        //conn.Close();
    }
}

Item 3: Script Transformation

select into #(#)temporary_table2 with another column of value '!!!'



#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
#endregion

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    private SqlConnection conn = null;
    private SqlCommand cmd = null;
    private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    private int counter_PreExecute = 0;
    private int counter_Input0_ProcessInput = 0;
    private int counter_Input0_ProcessInputRow = 0;
    private int counter_PostExecute = 0;
    string selectQuery = "";

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        conn = (SqlConnection)Connections.Connection.AcquireConnection(null);

        counter_PreExecute += 1;
        if (counter_PreExecute == 1)
        {

            string pattern = @"SELECT *, '!!!' as col3
{0}
FROM #temporary_table;";

            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            selectQuery = string.Format(pattern, "INTO ##temporary_table2_PreExecute");
            cmd.CommandText = selectQuery;
            var msg = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();

        counter_PostExecute += 1;
        if (counter_PostExecute == 1)
        {

            string pattern = @"SELECT *, '!!!' as col3
{0}
FROM #temporary_table;";

            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            selectQuery = string.Format(pattern, "INTO ##temporary_table2_PostExecute");
            cmd.CommandText = selectQuery;
            var msg = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
        {

        counter_Input0_ProcessInputRow += 1;
        if (counter_Input0_ProcessInputRow == 1)
        {

            string pattern = @"SELECT *, '!!!' as col3
{0}
FROM #temporary_table;";

            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            selectQuery = string.Format(pattern, "INTO ##temporary_table2_Input0_ProcessInputRow");
            cmd.CommandText = selectQuery;
            var msg = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        Row.Col3 = "1";
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
    {
        base.Input0_ProcessInput(Buffer);
        counter_Input0_ProcessInput += 1;
        if (counter_Input0_ProcessInput == 1)
        {

            string pattern = @"SELECT *, '!!!' as col3
{0}
FROM #temporary_table;";

            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            //selectQuery = getSelectQuery("INTO ##temporary_table2");
            selectQuery = string.Format(pattern, "INTO ##temporary_table2_Input0_ProcessInput");
            cmd.CommandText = selectQuery;
            var msg = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
        }
    }

}

Item 4: OLE DB Destination

Write #(#)temporary_table2 to regular_table

This cannot be reached by the data of the temporary table since the filled temp table pops up only in the PostExecute() method - after the output has already been fed with the data from the data flow.
I leave it in the model to show that it cannot be done, unless:

you save the temp table to a regular table (at best on Staging to have the footprint in the production logs) or
you save the temp table as a file

before entering another Script Component that reads the regular table or file into the PreExecute method and puts the data into the output arrow in the Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row) method. Only then it will be in the downstream flow of the DFT again.
Checks
I had many problems to set this up since the temp table was dropped during "Script Component 2" (item 3) and in times strangely came back after the run had ended. I thought it depended on which of the three main methods hosted the code, but it was unclear. I did not change any settings anymore, sometimes it worked, mostly not, so that I thought it would be a rights issue of the connection manager. The new thing is now that I query something like select * into ##tmpTable2 from ##tmpTable1 and since then, all tables get always filled, the whole code works. I tought that this perhaps means that you have to SQL-touch the table to keep it or bring it back to life. It then became clear that the temp tables are only then filled with data if you run SQL code in the PostExecute() method. The same code pasted in the other three methods fails.
On 2024-04-22, I checked this again with global (##) temp tables where a ##temporary_table with two columns comes in, and a third column is selected into ##temporary_table2.

And the table2 is empty when the table1 comes in empty, and that happens in all methods but the PostExecute() method.
The code to check this was as follows (with the name suffix always like the method name):
        string pattern = @"SELECT *, '!!!' as col3
{0}
FROM ##temporary_table;";

        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        selectQuery = string.Format(pattern, "INTO ##temporary_table2_PostExecute");
        cmd.CommandText = selectQuery;
        var msg = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

240422 Check 2: Full code not with global ##temporary_table, but with #temporary_table

PreExecute() method
In the PreExecute() method, the same code throws:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name tmpTable.

New check on 20240422 with ##temporary_table:

Check 2 with #temporary_table throws the same error as above:

Yet, there is a table with a long suffix, as all #temp tables get:

I cannot have a look at it:

I can only have a look at global ##temp tables, which come in empty in this method.
Input0_ProcessInput() method
Changing this method was said in Can I add rows to Output Buffer in SSIS Script Component in PostExecute?. But it did not help in finding a workaround as the tmpTable1 itself arrives empty at the public override void Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer) method.
If you override the public override void Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer) method as the code that feeds the output arrow, you find an empty 0-rows tmpTable1, and what is more, the SQL runs at least one time again even if it should just run once so that you have to add a condition like:
    public override void Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
    {
        counter_Input0_ProcessInput += 1;
        if (counter_Input0_ProcessInput == 1)
        {

to avoid:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'There is already an object named '##tmpTable2' in the database.'

As tmpTable1 comes in empty, the method cannot work anyway.
New check on 20240422 shows the same:

20240422 Check 2:

I cannot have a look at the #temp table in this method.
20240422 Check 3 (get data from #tempTable and write to ##tempTable) fails as well, the ##table2 is empty:

Input0_ProcessInputRow() method
It is the same outcome if you run it in the loop over the rows:
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        counter_Input0_ProcessInputRow += 1;
        if (counter_Input0_ProcessInputRow == 1)
        {

As the [dbo].[##temporary_table] comes in empty, you cannot have any data in the table2 either:

20240422 Check 2: And this does not work with #temporary_table either:

20240422 Check 3 (from #tmpTable to ##tmpTable2) leads to an empty ##tmpTable2:

PostExecute() method
Once you enter the PostExecute() method, you can see the ##temporary_table from the first Script Component.



20240422 Check 2:
Even in PostExecute() where ##temp tables can be looked at in SSMS, the #temporary_table data cannot be seen:


20240422 Check 3 (getting data from #tempTable and write it to #tempTable2) fails, which shows that you cannot work with those #temp tables either:

On a second run, it worked, perhaps I have made a mistake during debugging before? Anyway, this proves that you can get the data from those #tmpTables in the PostExecute() method:

Wrapping up
You can only see the #(#) temporary tables in the PostExecute() method. Btw. if you try it with #temp tables, they look like this:

But that is how #temp tables always look like.
And if you select from #tmpTable1 into a global ##tmpTable2, you can see the data only in and after the PostExecute() method:

This shows that at least with my settings and code, the #tmpTable and the ##tmpTable both have the same behaviour: their data can only be worked on in the PostExecute() method.
This is bad news since in the PostExecute() method, you cannot feed the output arrow of the Script Component with the data anymore, that is why it is called "Post"-"Execute" (with "Execute" meaning to feed the output arrow). That means: once you begin to work with global ## temp tables, you are stuck in doing so.
I am happy if someone else can prove me wrong on this. The code above is ready to copy and paste to check all of this.
How do I feed the output arrow (Input0_ProcessInputRow()) of a second Script Component with data from a temp table of the first Script Component?
The data of the temp table must be there before the output arrow is fed by the Input0_ProcessInputRow() method. The data seems to come in only during the PostExecute() method, which comes after the Input0_ProcessInputRow() method and is therefore too late to feed the arrow.
